# How do you make the fields read-only in a Django form when a specific condition is met?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-3.0

Based on the following image, I am trying to make the fields category and current points non-editable when the status of the task is `Finalized` or `Cancelled`, otherwise the fields should be editable.

[image]

Below is the code from my html file.

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load widget_tweaks %} 
{% block content %}

<div id="form-group">
    <form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Select your category</label>
        {{ form.category|add_class:"card" }}
    <label>What's the status of the task?</label>
        {{ form.status|add_class:"card" }}
    <label>Current points:</label>
        {{ form.points|add_class:"card" }}
    <label>Finalized date:</label>
        {{ form.ending_date|add_class:"card" }}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Below is the code from my `forms.py` file.

```
class TaskModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Task
        fields = ['category', 'status', 'points']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['status'].required = False
        self.fields['points'].required = False
```

When I want to edit the contents of this form I need to verify if the status is Finalized, so the fields are non-editable, otherwise the fields should be editable and I am thinking something about:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load widget_tweaks %} 
{% block content %}

{% if form.status.value == 'Active' %} <!--make the fields editable -->
<div id="form-group">
    <form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Select your category</label> 
        {{ form.category|add_class:"card" }} 
    ...
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
   </form>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if form.status.value == 'Finalized' %} <!--make the fields non-editable -->
<div id="form-group">
    <form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Select your category</label> 
        {{ form.category|add_class:"card" }} 
   ...
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
   </form>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

However, I believe my approach might not work because this could be a more front-end problem rather than back-end one (just a guess). Can you point me out to the right direction to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the status is something that the user selects, you can't address your requirement with Python (Django) running on the server. You have to address it with a JavaScript running in the web page that displays the form. Something like this will definitely do the trick.

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load widget_tweaks %} 
{% block content %}

<body onload="makeReadOnly();">
  <div id="form-group">
    <form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="tweet-composer">
          <label>Insert your task</label>
          {{ form.task|add_class:"card js-keeper-editor" }}
        </div>
         <label>Select your category</label>
          {{ form.category|add_class:"card" }}
        <label>Current points:</label>
          {{ form.points|add_class:"card" }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
    </form>
 </div>
</body>
{% endblock content %}

<script type="text/javascript">
{% block jquery %}

 function makeReadOnly()
 {        
  if (document.getElementById('id_status').value == 'Finalized'){
      document.getElementById('id_task').readOnly=true;
      document.getElementById('id_category').readOnly=true;
 }else if (document.getElementById('id_status').value == 'Active'){ 
      document.getElementById('id_task').readOnly=true;
      document.getElementById('id_category').readOnly=false;
  }
 }
 document.getElementById('id_status').addEventListener('change', makeReadOnly);
{% endblock %}
</script>
```

With the "view page source" you can see the HTML structure that Django generates out of your form, so that you can identify the right bits with JQuery selectors. Alternatively you can do

```
f = SomethingForm()
f.as_p()
```

in the `./manage.py shell` console.

At the Django end, you may need custom form validation to handle the inter-dependency between the value of status and whether the other fields are required or not.